# Java передать данные из одного класса в другой

Tags: java

В проекте есть два класса:

Класс 1 "SerialTest1" С помощью библиотеки rxtx через последовательный порт передаёт данные в консоль. System.out.println("Данные: " + inputLine);

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class SerialTest1 implements SerialPortEventListener {

    SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {
            /*"/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
            "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux*/
            "COM10", // Windows
    };
    /**
     * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader
     * converting the bytes into characters
     * making the displayed results codepage independent
     */
    private BufferedReader input;
    /** The output stream to the port */
    private OutputStream output;
    /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and
        // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
        System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "COM10");

        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);
            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    //This should be called when you stop using the port.
    //This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine = input.readLine();
                System.out.println("Данные: " + inputLine);
                //return inputLine;
                //UDPClient.joyDataMain(inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // return joyData;
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
}
```

Второй класс UDPClient отправляет данные на сервер через консоль.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient  {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        SerialTest st = new SerialTest();

        while (true){

            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("37500000000.dyndns.mts.by");

            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

            String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
            System.out.print("Вы ввели: " + sentence);

            sendData = sentence.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 4445);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println(" FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
        }

       // clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как данные из класса SerialTest1, перенести данные в класс UDPClient. Чтобы данные из последовательного порта передавались на сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал отдельный класс InpitData, теперь данные из последовательного порта (это USB, кому не понятно) передаются через интернет (UDP протоколу если кто не заметил) в андройд приложение. Спасибо тем кто может пытался помочь, одно ясно, с сложными заданиями лучше обращаться к freelancer

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class InpitData implements SerialPortEventListener {

  SerialPort serialPort;
  /** The port we're normally going to use. */
  private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {
          /*"/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
          "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
          "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux*/
          "COM10", // Windows
  };
  /**
   * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader
   * converting the bytes into characters
   * making the displayed results codepage independent
   */
  private BufferedReader input;
  /** The output stream to the port */
  private OutputStream output;
  /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
  private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
  /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
  private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

  public void initialize() {
    // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and
    // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
    System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "COM10");

    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
      CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
      for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
        if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
          portId = currPortId;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (portId == null) {
      System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
              TIME_OUT);

      // set port parameters
      // задаем параметры порта
      serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
              SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
              SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
              SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

      input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
      output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

      serialPort.addEventListener(this);
      serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
  }

  public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
      serialPort.removeEventListener();
      serialPort.close();
    }
  }

  public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
      try {

        String inputLine = input.readLine();
        System.out.println(inputLine);

        //BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("375330000000.dyndns.mts.by");
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        sendData = inputLine.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 4445);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println(" FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
        //System.out.println(inputLine);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    InpitData main = new InpitData();
    main.initialize();
    Thread t = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {Thread.sleep(1000000);

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
      }
    };
    t.start();
    System.out.println("Started");
  }
}
```